How to see if Azure subscription is S0 or F0?
I want to access the Azure free tier of text-to-speech that includes 5 million characters in standard voices and 500,000 characters in neural voices, each month (this page, then click on "See all free services", then scroll to "Text-to-speech"):


Apparently, this is only valid for resources in the F0 tier; if a resource is in S0, charges start immediately without this free quota.
I did the free trial, then upgraded the plan to keep using, choosing "Basic". But I cannot find where to check that the subscription is F0, nor can I find pointers to find that.
How can I check which type of subscription (F0 or S0) I have on Microsoft, and what charges to expect from text-to-speech?
